# REACT TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with my code when I try to render my react app and I can't get rid of that. I'm a beginner. I want to create a simple counter and then use it as a shopping basket. Can you help me?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button
          className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
          onClick={() => this.props.onIncrement(this.props.counter)}
        >
          Increment
        </button>

        <button
          className="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2"
          onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.counter.id)}
        >
          X
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
  getBadgeClasses() {
    let classes = 'badge m-2 badge-';
    classes += this.props.counter.value === 0 ? 'warning' : 'primary';
    return classes;
  }
  formatCount() {
    const { value } = this.props.counter;
    return value === 0 ? 'Zero' : value;
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

classes += this.props.counter.value === 0 ? "warning" : "primary"; form example it shows problem here with **value**.

Comment: You have to set values in state. Can you share complete demo code?

Comment: https://codepen.io/medamis/pen/GwWMqG here is my counters (main) component. I have state counters here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on your codepen https://codepen.io/medamis/pen/GwWMqG you are passing `value={counter.value}` instead of `counter={counter}`.

Also, I've made some changes, so your code works, and created a [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/53j4vykzyp)

Also, I have some recommendations to your code:

1. Avoid creating function inline, if you can define it as class method.
2. Use getters and setters if necessary

Comment: thank you! It works, and i will keep in mind your recommendations. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it with State..

initialize your values before use.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

interface CounterState {
    currentCount: number;
}

export class Counter extends React {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { currentCount: 0 };
    }

    public render() {
        return <div>
            <h1>Counter</h1>

            <p>This is a simple example of a React component.</p>

            <p>Current count: <strong>{ this.state.currentCount }</strong></p>

            <button onClick={ () => { this.incrementCounter() } }>Increment</button>
        </div>;
    }

    incrementCounter() {
        this.setState({
            currentCount: this.state.currentCount + 1
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use state, not properties, to model the state of a component. [This guide is very useful](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) to understand the state of react components.

Using this principles I created a working example of your code below.

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {counter: 0};
  }

  incrementer(){
    return () => 
      {this.setState((state, props) => {
        state.counter = state.counter + 1;
        return state;
      })};
    
  }
  
  reseter(){
    return () => 
      this.setState({counter:0});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</div>
        <button
          className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
          onClick={this.incrementer()}
        >
          Increment
        </button>

        <button
          className="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2"
          onClick={this.reseter()}
        >
          X
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
  getBadgeClasses() {
    let classes = 'badge m-2 badge-';
    classes += this.state.counter === 0 ? 'warning' : 'primary';
    return classes;
  }
  
  formatCount() {
    return this.state.counter === 0 ? 'Zero' : 
      this.state.counter;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Counter />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/4.1.3/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Base on this [pen](https://codepen.io/medamis/pen/GwWMqG), it looks like you are not passing anything as `counter` prop to the `<Counter/>` component